# What is a 3.6V / 4.2V LiPo cell? (as opposed to 3.6/4.1 or 3.7/4.2)

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging

I am familiar with 3.6V/4.1V and 3.7V/4.2V LiPo cells.  I have a bunch of cells rated at 3.6V/4.2V.  What's up with the odd rating?  Can these be safely charged with a 4.2V charger IC such as the [MCP73831](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/20001984g-846362.pdf)?

This is all the info I have on the cells:

Models: Sony NP-FD1, NP-FT1, or NP-BD1
Nominal voltage: 3.6V
Maximum charge voltage: DC 4.2 V
Maximum charge current: 1.24 A
Typical capacity: 2.4Wh (680mAh)

(All three models have the same form factor and power specs but different keying; thanks Sony)

[image: Image of the three batteries]

**Addendum**

The battery voltage reads as 4.20V after being fully charged using the original charger.  I opened up the charger and the charge control is being done by an [M34501E4FP microcontroller](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/720/4500-720/4501/device/M34501E4FP.html) so no clues there.

Comment: 4.2v is a normal lithium ion cell.  The nominal voltage can be defined different ways, so being 100mV different is not meaningful.

Comment: @user1850479 That's what I'm thinking.  I reckon that as long as I keep the charge current under 1.24A all should be good (the chargers I want to use max out at 500mA).  The oldest of these batteries (and the charger I mentioned) date from 2001 so perhaps the 3.6V rating is a result of the nomenclature not yet being standardized or the chemistry of the time plateauing at a slightly lower voltage.  Given that these are Sony batteries though I wouldn't be surprised if they were doing something odd.